# Line 5: Char 54: error: no matching function for call to 'min(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type)'

Tags: c++, string, stl

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseStr(string s, int k) {
        for (int start = 0; start < s.size(); start += 2 * k) {
            int end = min(start + k - 1, s.size() - 1);
            while (start < end) {
                swap(s[start], s[end]);
                start++;
                end--;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
};
```

Line 5: Char 54: error: no matching function for call to 'min(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string::size_type)'

Comment: The arguments to `std::min()` **must** all be the same type! So, for example, you could cast the 2nd as: `int(s.size()) - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler tries to tell you, the issue is that the types of `start + k -1` and `s.size() - 1` are different. So one way to fix this is to change the types of `start` and `k` to `std::size_t`:

```
std::string reverseStr(std::string s, std::size_t k) {
    for (std::size_t start = 0; start < s.size(); start += 2 * k) {
        std::size_t end = std::min(start + k - 1, s.size() - 1);
        while (start < end) {
            swap(s[start], s[end]);
            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Alternatively you can just cast `s.size() - 1` to `int`:

```
int end = std::min(start + k - 1, static_cast<int>(s.size() - 1));
```

There is also the third way to explicitly specify the template parameter of `std::min`, but that might trigger signed-to-unsigned / unsigned-to-signed conversion warnings of your compiler:

```
int end = std::min<int>(start + k - 1, s.size() - 1);
```

Comment: static_cast<int> worked best!